# make a global object in java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to make an array of objects and use it in different functions. I wrote this pseudocode

```
privat stock[] d;

privat stock example;


public void StockCheck(){
    d =new stock[2];

    d[0]= new stock("a","test1", 22);
    d[1]= new stock("b","test2", 34);


}



@Override
public stock getStock(String name) throws StockCheckNotFoundException{

    int i;          
    System.out.println("ok" + name + d.legth); // error 
    example = new stock("example","example",2);
    return example;
}
```

In class test I make an instance of getStock and I call the function getStock stock.getStock();

I get a NullPointerExeption when I do d.length. d is null but I don't understand why.

Comment: We still don't know the name of your class, nor when `StockCheck()` is called.

Comment: You'd have to show us your real code, or we can't see what's wrong with it. This has numerous problems and wouldn't even compile.

Comment: also, you wrongly spelled 'length' and  'private'

Comment: Also, you should name classes starting with a capital letter eg `Stock`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perhaps this example of code will do what you need, using three classes

- Test - the main test code
- Stock - the implied code for Stock from your question
- StockCheck - the corrected code from your question.

(Note: you may really want to use an ArrayList inside StockQuote so you can add and delete Stocks.)

**Test class**

```
package stackJavaExample;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] testNames = {"test1","test2","notThere"};
        StockCheck mStockCheck = new StockCheck();

        for (int i=0; i<testNames.length; i++) {
            Stock result = mStockCheck.getStock(testNames[i]);
            if (result == null) {
                System.out.println("No stock for name: " + testNames[i]);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Found stock: " + result.getName() + ", " + result.getSymbol() + ", " + result.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Stock class**

```
package stackJavaExample;
public class Stock {
    private String symbol;
    private String name;
    private double value;
    public Stock(String symbol, String name, double value) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getSymbol() { return symbol;}
    public String getName() { return name;}
    public double getValue() {return value;}
}
```

**StockCheck class**

```
package stackJavaExample;
public class StockCheck {
    private Stock[] d;
    public StockCheck() {
        d = new Stock[2];
        d[0] = new Stock("a","test1", 22);
        d[1] = new Stock("b","test2", 34);
    }
    public Stock getStock(String name) {
        for (int i=0; i < d.length; i++) {
            if (d[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                return d[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmm. If that is in any way like your real code, then the problem is that your "constructor" isn't really a constructor, as you've declared it to return void, making it an ordinary method instead. Remove tbat "void" and it may fix the problem!

Comment: Should correct question or add comment to obtain clarification, since the question is pseudocode and not compilable Java code.